# I can not add Navigation Drawer in intelli J Idea

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-13

I am unable to add navigation in drawer in intelli J idea.
Can any one please tell me how can I add navigation drawer in intelliJ idea.

Comment: Pls provide more details about your problem, what error or phenomenon do you meet?

Comment: @OwenTsao I Want to know the steps how to add the feature.

Comment: Follow this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html, there is a sample app, you can download it and import in intellij